# Move Shape visible

Tags: excel, vba, move, shapes, visible

I'm trying to move a group of pictures in Excel with VBA, this works fine, but I want that the user can see how the picture is moving.

It's for a little game, a "Horse Race".

Here is my code for moving the horses.

```
Sub TrackProgress()
Dim Tracks() As GroupObject
Dim Agents(), HorseCount As Integer
Dim AgentCount As Integer
Dim TrackCount As Integer
Dim Progress As Double
Dim MaxPx As Double

AgentCount = Sheets("Config").Range("O5").Value
TrackCount = Round(AgentCount / HorsesPerTrack, 0)
ReDim Tracks(1 To TrackCount)
ReDim Agents(1 To AgentCount)
MaxPx = Sheets("Config").Range("O15").Value


Sheets("HorseRaceTrack").Select

For i = 6 To Sheets("Config").Cells(Rows.Count, 5).End(xlUp).Row

    If Sheets("Config").Cells(i, 4).Value = "Active" Then
        Agents(i - 5) = Sheets("Config").Cells(i, 5).Value
    End If

Next i

For i = 1 To AgentCount

    If Not IsError(Sheets("Config").Cells(i + 5, 7).Value) Then
        Progress = Sheets("Config").Cells(i + 5, 7).Value
        Do Until Sheets("HorseRaceTrack").Shapes("Horse_" & Agents(i)).Left >= (MaxPx * Progress)
            Sheets("HorseRaceTrack").Shapes("Horse_" & Agents(i)).IncrementLeft 1.3636220472
            'Sleep 1000 ' Pferd beweg sich nicht flüssig....
        Loop
    Else
        GoTo NextOne
    End If

NextOne:
Next i

End Sub
```

I already tried to use "sleep 500" but the screen is also freezing

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Not sure what your issue is. Is your issue that the shape is not moving? or your code is throwing an error message? or `screen is freezing`? or the combination?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put a `DoEvents` immediately after the `.IncrementLeft`.  This should allow the worksheet to display the Shape as it moves.

By adjusting the size of the increment, you can get the motion to speed-up or slow-down.